Sending Azure storage queue message though a registered and enterprise application
I am trying to create an Azure application using Python as a desktop application, at first I created a registered application (and called it testapp1) as a multi-tenant (Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant))

Then, I created an exposed API, and granted it the following permission

Microsft Graph => user.read => Sign in and read the user profile
Azure Storage => User_impersonation => Access Azure storage
Generated_API => SendMessages ==> Allow the app to send messages to Azure storage

for the final part of the application configuration, I have granted the application owner (user1).
After that, I created a storage account (sorage_acc1) and message queue (message_1), and granted the following permission to it

User1 => Storage Queue Data Message Sender
testapp1 => Storage Queue Data Message Sender

When I tested my configuration to see if I could send a message queue using this application using an Azure AD join windows 11 machine message I was sent without any issue.
from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential
from azure.storage.queue import QueueClient
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceExistsError, HttpResponseError

# Authenticate using InteractiveBrowserCredential with client ID
credential = InteractiveBrowserCredential()

# Create a QueueClient
queue_client = QueueClient(
    additionally_allowed_tenants="[*]",
    account_url="https://sorage_acc1.queue.core.windows.net/",
    queue_name="message_1",
    credential=credential
)

try:
    # Send a message to the queue
    queue_client.send_message("Your message here")
    print("Message sent successfully!")
except ResourceExistsError:
    print("The queue already exists.")
except HttpResponseError as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e.message}")

For the final test, I have used this code in another windows 11 machine that is joined to another domain but it failed (I have granted admin consent). what did I do wrong in this scenario
Error message
An error occurred: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
RequestId:XXXXX 
Time:2024-09-19T14:21:41.8678546Z
ErrorCode:InvalidAuthenticationInfo
authenticationerrordetail:Issuer validation failed. Issuer did not match.

Edit1:
I have changed the code to
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.queue import QueueClient
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceExistsError, HttpResponseError

# Authenticate using ClientSecretCredential with client ID and client secret
credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id="common", 
    client_id="AAAAAAAA",
    client_secret="XXXXXXX",
    additionally_allowed_tenants=["*"]
)

# Create a QueueClient
queue_client = QueueClient(
    account_url="https://sorage_acc1.queue.core.windows.net/",
    queue_name="message_1",
    credential=credential
)

try:
    # Send a message to the queue
    queue_client.send_message("Your message here")
    print("Message sent successfully!")
except ResourceExistsError:
    print("The queue already exists.")
except HttpResponseError as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e.message}")

I got the following error
ClientSecretCredential.get_token failed: Authentication failed: AADSTS7000229: The client application AAAAAAAA is missing service principal in the tenant BBBBBBBB. See instructions here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2225119 Trace ID: 081abc3d-6733-41c4-83e1-0dd7a9a52600 Correlation ID: 808b88f9-3a16-4eb2-9376-35faae24ccfb Timestamp: 2024-09-20 09:23:34Z
ClientSecretCredential.get_token failed: Authentication failed: AADSTS7000229: The client application AAAAAAAA is missing service principal in the tenant BBBBBBBB. See instructions here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2225119 Trace ID: 28816962-57ed-48e9-a4d3-da9530d11100 Correlation ID: ec234fad-b931-4284-a26e-c3297824b26e Timestamp: 2024-09-20 09:23:50Z
ClientSecretCredential.get_token failed: Authentication failed: AADSTS7000229: The client application AAAAAAAA is missing service principal in the tenant BBBBBBBB. See instructions here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2225119 Trace ID: a05f9c09-c497-442e-b1bb-f9de45b63100 Correlation ID: f84ddfc6-fc77-4143-bee5-a806886928b2 Timestamp: 2024-09-20 09:24:16Z
ClientSecretCredential.get_token failed: Authentication failed: AADSTS7000229: The client application AAAAAAAA is missing service principal in the tenant BBBBBBBB. See instructions here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2225119 Trace ID: d033c96a-b917-4c35-a508-b2b78c921c00 Correlation ID: e0a92cc9-f88e-42da-85a6-cc3c7ba396ab Timestamp: 2024-09-20 09:24:58Z
An error occurred: Authentication failed: AADSTS7000229: The client application AAAAAAAA is missing service principal in the tenant BBBBBBBB. See instructions here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2225119 Trace ID: d033c96a-b917-4c35-a508-b2b78c921c00 Correlation ID: e0a92cc9-f88e-42da-85a6-cc3c7ba396ab Timestamp: 2024-09-20 09:24:58Z

following the instructions in the link provided by Microsoft will provide the following error
New-MgServicePrincipal_CreateExpanded: The service principal cannot be created, updated, or restored because the service principal name AAAAAAAA is already in use.

Did you specify your client ID etc. in InteractiveBrowserCredential()?

Hi @juunas, yes, I have tried to add it but it did not work it has to do with tenant_id="common"

Without the client ID or the Storage user_impersonation scope, the resulting token will not be able to access the Storage account for sure. Are you able to see in the login window if it specifies the Azure Storage scope in the URL?

@juunas, permission for the app is "Azure Storage => User_impersonation => Access Azure storage" and I have tried with and without client ID, secret.
